# How disable chrome extension from popup menu?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i create my extension and i want create disable/enable button to popup menu in my chrome extension

i has created popup.html file

```
 <button id="disable">Disable</button>
```

and i has created popup.js file

```
 function disable_ext()
    {
      console.log ('111');
    }
    document.querySelector('#disable').addEventListener('click', disable_ext);
```

if simply open in browser popup.html file and press disable button then in console i see "111" result, but if open popup.html in menu (click in icon of extension left button of mouse) and has been press disable button then there is no result in the console "111"

How correct create event from button to disable chrome extension?

Comment: 1) The popup is a separate window. To see its devtools right-click the popup, then click "Inspect". 2) To disable extensions use [chrome.management API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management)

Comment: This is work, thank you

Comment: @Besha, can you please post the solution that worked for you? I am trying to achieve same thing

Comment: @Nizar Kadri i have posted solution for your request

Answer (score 1):

answer to this question

popup.html

```
<button id="disable">Disable</button>
```

popup.js

```
function disable_ext()
{
  var id = chrome.runtime.id;
  chrome.management.get(id, function(ex)
    {
        if(ex.enabled)
          {
            chrome.management.setEnabled(id, false);
          }
    });
}

document.querySelector('#disable').addEventListener('click', disable_ext);
```